# Copy data from two separate textboxes to one txt file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

I am searching all the exe,dll or both files in a particular folder.
I wish to **copy the data in the same way in txt file as it is displayed in the textboxes** like 
(FileName| Path.....) pair value. **File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\BigB.txt",files.ToArray());** will copy only the path in BigB.txt but I can't get them in the way shown below

```
File1.exe                Path1
File2.exe                Path2
    .                      . 
    .                      . 
    .                      .
```

since I can't use something like **File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\BigB.txt,Path.GetFileName(files) + files.ToArray())"**

Though I have an idea of copying all the filenames in another list, like this

```
List<String> filename = new List<String>();
        filename.AddRange(files);
```

and then copying the data into txt file with the help of both the lists. But then again how to go through each entry one by one ? :|

XAML Code

```
<Window x:Class="FileFinder.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="FileCopier"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Width="1366" Height="758">
<Grid Background="LavenderBlush">

    <Label Height="40" Margin="240,0,234,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="28" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="DarkSeaGreen" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Broadway">Welcome To</Label>

    <Label Height="55" Margin="194,35,194,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="45" Foreground="Chocolate" FontFamily="Colonna MT">FILE FINDER</Label>

    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" AutoWordSelection="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="444.419,211,20,21" Name="textbox1" Background="Pink" Opacity="0.5" ScrollBar.Scroll="Scroll" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBox>

    <Button ToolTip="Click to search exe files" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="366,96,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" Background="LavenderBlush" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkSeaGreen" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkSeaGreen" Click="button1_Click" FontFamily="Broadway" Cursor="Hand">.exe</Button>

    <Button ToolTip="Click to search dll files" Margin="602,96,619,0" Name="button2" Background="LavenderBlush" BorderBrush="DarkSeaGreen" Foreground="DarkSeaGreen" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Click="button2_Click" FontFamily="Broadway" Cursor="Hand" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top">.dll</Button>

    <Button Background="LavenderBlush" BorderBrush="DarkSeaGreen" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkSeaGreen" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,96,383,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122" Click="button3_Click" FontFamily="Broadway">All</Button>

    <Label FontFamily="Broadway" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" Height="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="12,165,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="320" Opacity="0.6">Filename</Label>

    <Label FontFamily="Broadway" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" Height="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,165,234,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0.6" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="86.627">Path</Label>

    <Button  Name="button4" Click="button4_Click" Width="32" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,173,175,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Background="LavenderBlush" ToolTip="PageUp">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="C:\Users\Vipul.Sharma\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\FileFinder\FileFinder\PageUp.png"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <Button Name="button5" Click="button5_Click" Width="32" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,173,140,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Background="LavenderBlush" ToolTip="PageUp">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="C:\Users\Vipul.Sharma\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\FileFinder\FileFinder\PageDown.png" Opacity="0.7"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" AutoWordSelection="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="20,211,0,21" Name="textbox2" Background="Pink" Opacity="0.5" ScrollBar.Scroll="Scroll" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="418.697"></TextBox>    
</Grid>
```

C# Code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> files = new List<String>();
        String[] extensions = new String[] { "*.exe" };

        foreach (String extension in extensions)
        {
            String[] lol = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (String file in lol)
                files.Add(file);
        }

        textbox1.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            textbox2.Text += Path.GetFileName(files[i]) + "\n";
            textbox1.Text += files[i] + "\n";
        }           
    }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> files = new List<String>();
        String[] extensions = new[] { "*.dll" };

        foreach (String extension in extensions)
        {
            String[] lol = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\", "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (String file in lol)
                files.Add(file);
        }
        textbox1.Clear();
        textbox1.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            textbox2.Text += Path.GetFileName(files[i])+ "\n";
            textbox1.Text += files[i] + "\n";
        }            
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> files = new List<String>();
        String[] extensions = new[] { "*.dll", "*.exe" };

        foreach (String extension in extensions)
        {
            String[] lol = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (String file in lol)
                files.Add(file);
        }
        textbox1.Clear();
        textbox1.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            textbox2.Text += Path.GetFileName(files[i]) + "\n";
            textbox1.Text += files[i] + "\n";

        }

        foreach (String extension in extensions)
        {
            String[] lol = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\", "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (String file in lol)
                files.Add(file);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            textbox2.Text += Path.GetFileName(files[i]) + "\n";
            textbox1.Text += files[i] + "\n";
        }
    }


private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox2.PageUp();
        textbox1.PageUp();
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.PageDown();
        textbox2.PageDown();
    }

//To synchronize scrollbar of textbox1 and textbox2
    private void Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == textbox1)
        {
            textbox1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue);
        }
        else
        {
            textbox1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Path.GetFullPath(files[i]` to get the path for the particular file.
then print this along with the Path.GetFileName.

Modify your code like following

```
List<string> lstResult = new List<string>();
for(int i=0; i<files.Length;i++)
{
    lstResult.Add(Path.GetFileName(files[i]) + "           " + Path.GetFullPath(files[i]));
}
Files.WriteAllLines(lst);
```

try to follow the logic. since coding was typed in a non-ide mode

Comment: @Mohamed 
   
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
   {
       File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\BigB.txt",     Path.GetFileName(files[i]) + "\t" + Path.GetFullPath(files[i]) + "\n");
   }

Sorry that didn't worked,gives error

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mohamed ! Just a little modification was needed and it was alright.

`List<string> lstResult = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                lstResult.Add(Path.GetFileName(files[i]) + "           " + Path.GetFullPath(files[i]));
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\BigB.txt",lstResult.ToArray());`